# Python except None

Tags: python

Are there any unexpected side effects of using "except None"? The behavior I expect is that nothing will be caught by that clause which a few small tests seem to confirm.

Here is a rough outline of what I am trying to do. When no argument is provided to the function, exceptions=None which creates the "except None" clause. Just want to double check that I'm not going to catch something unexpected.

```
# exceptions is exception or set of exceptions I want to do special processing for
def check_exceptions(exceptions=None)
  try:                                                                            
    ...                                                                    
  except exceptions as e:                                                       
    ...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works fine here (under Python 2.x).

```
>>> try:
...   foo
... except None as e:
...   pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

> For an except clause with an expression, that expression is evaluated, and the clause matches the exception if the resulting object is “compatible” with the exception. An object is compatible with an exception if it is the class or a base class of the exception object, or a tuple containing an item compatible with the exception.

[source](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)

Therefore the expression doesn't *have* to be an exception type, it will simply fail to ever match.

This behavior was changed in Python 3.x, and the expression after `except` must be a descendant of `BaseException` or a tuple of such.

Comment: @Asad: You can't *raise* something that isn't an `Exception` descendant, but you can try to *catch* it (although you'll fail every time).

Comment: @Asad: Ah, I see. Seems like they forgot to update the langref for that one.

Comment: Maybe this could be updated to give an example how to achieve the same (exception type as function argument incl. "no exception" as default) in Python 3?

Comment: @NichtJens I believe `except ():` should work (a tuple of zero `BaseException` types).

Answer (score 1):

#### Python 3

```py
def check_exceptions(exceptions=())
  try:                                                                            
    ...                                                                    
  except exceptions as e:                                                       
    ...
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation if possible